# Rewind Stax Cursor to a specific cursor location?

Tags: xml, parsing, stax, woodstox

I know StAX is a pull parsing ... but i m wondering is there a possibility to save root cursor location/context.. visit child Cursor ...and later rewind root cursor to a saved location/context ?

Thanks

Comment: I finally chose to use: [VTD-XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTD-XML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there is no support for doing that in Stax API, or in Woodstox' extended API (stax2-api).

You could use `XMLEventReader`, store events, if that helps. It is still more efficient than re-parsing, although uses more memory than just holding on to underlying XML content.